# IntelliJ code style for specific variable names

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I am using Android Studio and in my code style settings I have this order for code generation:

1. Static fields
2. Instance fields
3. Constructors
4. Instance methods
5. Static methods
6. Inner classes
7. Static inner classes

This is fine, except for my classes which implement the `Parcelable` interface the `CREATOR` constant is moved to the top of my class like this:

```
public class Task implements Parcelable {

  public static final Parcelable.Creator<Task> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Task>() {
    public Task createFromParcel(final Parcel source) {
      return new Task(source);
    }

    public Task[] newArray(final int size) {
      return new Task[size];
    }
  };

  public static final Task[] EMPTY_TASK_ARRAY = new Task[0];

  private static final String TAG = Task.class.getSimpleName();

  private final DateTime mStartDate;
  private final DateTime mEndDate;
  private final int mId;
```

I want the `CREATOR` constant to appear at the bottom of the class, but I don't want to affect the positioning of other constants. Is there a way to apply a code style in IntelliJ for specific variable names (and even more useful would be to apply the code style to specific variable names in classes which only implement certain interfaces, e.g. Parcelable)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your own matching rule for specific variable names:

In Android-Studio go to Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java -> Arrangement

If you want the variable named CREATOR to appear on the bottom add a matching rule and position it accordingly:

> field public static final name:CREATOR

Check this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ck4Wu.png) for details.